# Colocar leyendas en un gráfico con líneas superpuestas en ggplot

Tags: r, dataframe, rstudio, ggplot2, theme

Realicé una gráfica con dos líneas superpuestas debido a que cada variable está en una columna diferente, obtuve los resultados esperados pero no he logrado colocar la leyenda para cada línea, les agradezco su amable ayuda.

EL código que estoy usando es el siguiente:

```
ggplot(velSed, aes(x=DiamPart, y= Eb*100)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_line(aes(y=Efm*100), colour="blue")+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(from = 0, to = 120, by = 5))+
  geom_hline(yintercept = 100, colour="green")+
  scale_y_continuous()+
  labs(title="Eficiencia de una Cámara de Sedimentación",hjust = 0.5,
       subtitle = "Flujo en Bloque y Flujo Mixto",
       tag = "A",
       caption="Fuente: Elaboración propia 2023") +
  xlab("Diametro de partícula (um)") +
  ylab("Eficiencia (%)")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  theme(legend.position = c(50, 250),
        legend.background = element_rect(fill = "white"))
```

| DiamPart | Eb | Efm |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.0003024691 | 0.0003024234 |
| 6 | 0.0108888889 | 0.0108298195 |
| 11 | 0.0365987654 | 0.0359371269 |
| 16 | 0.0774320988 | 0.0745101358 |
| 21 | 0.1333888889 | 0.1248753003 |
| 26 | 0.2044691358 | 0.1849201017 |
| 31 | 0.2906728395 | 0.2522397244 |
| 36 | 0.3920000000 | 0.3242958860 |
| 41 | 0.5084506173 | 0.3985733026 |
| 46 | 0.6400246914 | 0.4727205954 |
| 51 | 0.7867222222 | 0.5446651617 |
| 56 | 0.9485432099 | 0.6126951655 |
| 61 | 1.1254876543 | 0.6755058122 |
| 66 | 1.3175555556 | 0.7322109019 |
| 71 | 1.5247469136 | 0.7823238592 |
| 76 | 1.7470617284 | 0.8257147106 |
| 81 | 1.9845000000 | 0.8625506784 |
| 86 | 2.2370617284 | 0.8932282316 |
| 91 | 2.5047469136 | 0.9183037284 |
| 96 | 2.7875555556 | 0.9384284617 |
| 101 | 3.0854876543 | 0.9542922611 |
| 106 | 3.3985432099 | 0.9665780768 |
| 111 | 3.7267222222 | 0.9759283920 |
| 116 | 4.0700246914 | 0.9829230332 |

[image]

Comment: ¡Hola! ¿Puedes poner el resultado que te aparece al poner `dput(velSed)`? Eso facilitaría el ofrecerte ayuda.

Comment: Yo utilizaría pivot_longer para convertir el dataframe al formato de entrada preferido por ggplot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De la manera natural de `ggplot` las leyendas aparecen cuando se ha definido alguna dimensión estética como ser `color`. En tu caso esta dimensión debería ser el nombre del coeficiente, en tu caso `Eb` o `Efm`, el problema es que no tienes este dato, tienes los valores del mismo. Lo más fácil sería transformar la estructura "horizontal" a una "vertical" para generar la dimensión que determina el tipo de línea:

```
library(tidyverse)

velSed %>% 
  mutate(Eb = Eb * 100,
         Efm = Efm *100) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-DiamPart) %>% 
  select(DiamPart,
         Coeficiente = name,
         value) -> plot_data

plot_data

# A tibble: 48 × 3
   DiamPart Coeficiente     value
      <int> <chr>           <dbl>
 1        1 Eb           0.0302  
 2        1 Efm          0.000302
 3        6 Eb           1.09    
 4        6 Efm          0.0108  
 5       11 Eb           3.66    
 6       11 Efm          0.0359  
 7       16 Eb           7.74    
 8       16 Efm          0.0745  
 9       21 Eb          13.3     
10       21 Efm          0.125   
# … with 38 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Ahora teniendo la variable `Coeficiente` podemos "mapear" esta con el color y no necesitamos dos `geom_line()` ya que la dimensión `color` determina que sean efectivamente dos curvas independientes :

```
plot_data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = DiamPart, y = value, color = Coeficiente)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 100, colour="green") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(from = 0, to = 120, by = 5))+
  scale_y_continuous()+
  labs(title="Eficiencia de una Cámara de Sedimentación",hjust = 0.5,
       subtitle = "Flujo en Bloque y Flujo Mixto",
       tag = "A",
       caption="Fuente: Elaboración propia 2023") +
  xlab("Diametro de partícula (um)") +
  ylab("Eficiencia (%)")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Nota: Quité tu última sentencia `theme()` por que ocultaba las leyendas.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda, me ha servido muchísimo.